# Initializing a vector of structs

Tags: c++

Having trouble initializing a vector of structs.

Simplified Code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

struct info
{
    int num;
    bool b;

    info()
        : num(1), b(false){}
};

std::vector<info> stuff = std::vector<info>(10);

//Try 1
stuff[5] = info();
stuff[5].num = 4;

//Try 2
info inf;
inf.num = 5;
stuff.push_back(inf);

std::cout << "\nstuff[5].num=" << stuff[5].num
                    << "\nstuff[10].num=" << stuff[10].num;
return 0;
}
```

Not sure why this isn't working. It seems like it should be simple, but after each try all the Visual Studio debugger has is: stuff[(any)] = {num = ??? b = ???}

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How is it "not working"? It looks fine (although you don't need the `stuff[5] = info();` line.)

Comment: It works just fine (see [here](http://ideone.com/GZ9psK))... thing is understanding what it does: the `(10)` says to create an array initially containing 10 default-constructed `info` objects, then you overwrite the 6th (i.e. `[5]`) with another default-constructed (identical) object before updating its `num` field, then you `push_back` an 11th object on the `vector` with `num` of `5` and `b` left at its default of `false`.

Comment: If the problem is with VS debugger, state your version and perhaps include a screen shot of what you're seeing and where, showing where the breakpoint is in program execution.  For example, if you're breaking on the line declaring stuff it might not be constructed yet....

Comment: @Tony D I found the problem, after looking at your correct version. I was declaring the struct inside the function (which I was unaware was not ok in this case, though I'm not sure why) Thanks for your help. I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: What you did is OK in C++11. But if your code was not compiling, why are you talking about the debugger?

Comment: It was compiling. I was just using the debugger as a means to monitor the variables to see if they were being updated, which they were not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following does not fit into a comment.

The program is not working because it is incomplete. Always give a complete minimal example showing the problem. The following program prints out

```
stuff[5].num=4
stuff[10].num=5
```

as expected.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct info
{
    int num;
    bool b;

    info()
        : num(1), b(false){}
};

int main() {
    std::vector<info> stuff = std::vector<info>(10);

    //Try 1
    stuff[5] = info();
    stuff[5].num = 4;

    //Try 2
    info inf;
    inf.num = 5;
    stuff.push_back(inf);

    std::cout << "\nstuff[5].num=" << stuff[5].num
                        << "\nstuff[10].num=" << stuff[10].num;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem turns out to be quite interesting. From what the OP told us, the original code was something like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    struct info
    {
        int num;
        bool b;

        info()
            : num(1), b(false){}
    };

    std::vector<info> stuff = std::vector<info>(10);

    //Try 1
    stuff[5] = info();
    stuff[5].num = 4;

    //Try 2
    info inf;
    inf.num = 5;
    stuff.push_back(inf);

    std::cout << "\nstuff[5].num=" << stuff[5].num
                        << "\nstuff[10].num=" << stuff[10].num;
    return 0;
}

/*
    Local Variables:
    compile-command: "g++ -std=c++11 test.cc -o a.exe"
    End:
 */
```

If this is compiled with `g++` and without the option `-std=c++11` I get the following error message:

```
g++ -g /temp/test.cc -o /temp/test.exe && /temp/test.exe
/temp/test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
/temp/test.cc:15:18: error: template argument for ‘template<class> class std::allocator’ uses local type ‘main()::info’
  std::vector<info> stuff = std::vector<info>(10);
                  ^
/temp/test.cc:15:18: error:   trying to instantiate ‘template<class> class std::allocator’
/temp/test.cc:15:18: error: template argument 2 is invalid
...
```

But, Section [class.local] of N3797 tells us that nothing is wrong with the local class. Therefore, I retried with the `-std=c++11` option of `g++`. 
And this compiles fine and gives the expected result.

Compiling additionally with the `-g` flag for including debug information and debugging works with `g++`.

There follows the output of a part of the `gdb`-session just run before the `<<` operator:

```
(gdb) print stuff[5]
$2 = (__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<main()::info> >::value_type &) @0x60003c388: {num = 4, b = false}
(gdb) print stuff[10]
$3 = (__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<main()::info> >::value_type &) @0x60003c3b0: {num = 5, b = false}
```

As one sees it gives the expected results.

Visual Studio 2010 compiles it and the output in the console is fine. There is just nothing to see in the debugger. The `stuff`-members are scrap in the debugger even if the program is compiled in debug mode.

Comment: This is true. I included only the function body in the question (the entire thing being inside the function body being the reason it wasn't working.) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could somebody please explain the -1. I tried to post it as a comment. But, the program text was lost there. So I posted it here to help finding the origin of the problem.

Comment: I tried to upvote you, but did not have the reputation to do so. No idea about the -1.

Comment: It is not an answer. If the question does not have enough information to answer it, ask for clarification, vote to close, down-vote, etc.

Comment: @JamesP You see the comment of juanchopanza. He is right. Could you include your minimal running original code in the question? (If the  code in my edited answer represents it correctly you can use it.) I think this would complete the question.

Comment: @juanchopanza I think the question has now the right form for the site. Furthermore, it turned out to be a really interesting question (see my edit of the answer). AFAIK, the code is right according to the c++11 standard. Just Visual Studio gives not enough debugging information. Thanks to JamesP for improving the question!

Comment: @Tobias How can VS give debugging information for code that doesn't compile? That tells me that the question is not right yet. If it did compile, then what was the solution? Or are you saying OP's version of VS has a bug?

Comment: @juanchopanza It does compile now with `g++` and with VS (console application). Just the VS-debugger (VS2010 in my case) does not give the expected results as the OP wrote in his question and as I wrote in my answer.